# javascript selectors

Tags: javascript, dom, selector, traversal

How does one select DOM elements in javascript?
Like for example:

```
<div class="des">
    <h1>Test</h1>
        <div class="desleft">
          <p>Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="Right">
           <button>Test</button>
        </div>
</div>
```

Now how do i select `h1`? This is just a part of a bigger Page, so cannot use `getElementsByTagName()`, since others might get selected. Also since there might be other `h1`'s in the document later, i cannot attach the index(body's) to above.

Is there a simple way to select, say `<h1>` tag which is under the classname of `desleft`?
I cannot use jQuery or any other libraries.

Comment: It is simply not productive to not use some sort of selector library for modern day javascript programming.  If you can't use jQuery, then at least use Sizzle which is just a selector engine (and is what's used inside of jQuery and YUI).  It's quite small and will save you hundreds of hours of development, prevent lots of bugs and save you from lots of cross-browser issues.  It's simply not productive to reinvent the wheel yourself.

Comment: Yes, I absolutely agree.
I had a feeling there were ways to do it, and i did not know of them.

Comment: In any of those selector libraries, you would just use the selector: `".des h1"` to access the `<h1>` object in your example.  In Sizzle, it would just be: `var list = Sizzle(".des h1");`.

Comment: You probably don't need a library: http://caniuse.com/#search=querySelector

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
getElementsByTag()
```

Would be a function that you can start with, and then you can filter for the DOMElements that have the class.

```
var h1_array = document.getElementsByTag('h1');

var h1_class_array = [];
for (var i=0, len=h1_array.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (h1_array[i].className.indexOf('classname') !== -1) {
        h1_class_array.push(h1_array[i]);
    }
}
```

The `.indexOf` function returns `-1` if the needle is not found in the haystack.

Now re-reading your question, why not just give your h1's id's ?

DOM traversal is one of javascript's glaring issues (enter jQuery).

a simple `getElementById()` would save you a headache, and ids on all your h1's would be much cleaner in the end than trying to formulate an algorithm to select them by other means.

Comment: Thanks, that solves it :)
However, out of curiosity, let's say i use it to find around 5 different elements, and since an array is created for each of <h1>, <p>, etc, etc, since there are a lot of <p> or other tags, the array will get pretty big. In real world scenario, will it consume a lot of memory/processing?

Comment: Obviously without a given limitation all scenarios will eventually get outside the realm of acceptable, but again, vanilla javascript DOM traversal is one of those things you just grin and bear.

Comment: Well <h1> is just for an example, I'll have to use it for other elements, was wondering if there was an easy and neat  way to do DOM traversal using javascript. I guess, giving id's will have to be the smartest option, rather than increasing size and processing thanks just for traversals

Comment: yes, and this is exactly the issue that has given such popularity to the competing JavaScript libraries, as their primary function is DOM traversal and selection.

Answer (score 8):

You can use this to get to your H1:

```
var des = document.getElementsByClassName('des')
var fc = des[0].getElementsByTagName('h1')
alert(fc[0].innerHTML)
```

Answer (score 7):

w3.org has selectors now (http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/#examples). Here are 2 different ways that worked for me on Chrome. You may want to use querySelectorAll function that returns a list.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//looks for <h1> tag under <div> with className "des"
showOff1 = function() {
  var x = document.querySelector(".des h1");
  alert(x.innerHTML);      
}
//looks for <div> tag with className "desleft" and then use previousSibling to traceback <h1> tag
showOff2 = function() {
  var y = document.querySelector("div.desleft");
  var z = y.previousSibling.previousSibling;
  alert(z.innerHTML);      
}
</script>
<body onload="showOff2();">
```

Answer (score 7):

### Use querySelectorAll

You can use [`querySelectorAll`](http://devdocs.io/dom/document/queryselector):

```
// Will return a NodeList even if there is only one element found
var heading = document.querySelectorAll('.des > h1');

heading[1].style.color = 'red'; // NodeList is similar to an array
```

This will return a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList).

### or

Use [`querySelector`](http://devdocs.io/dom/document/queryselector) to return the first element found:

```
var first_heading = document.querySelector('.des > h1');

first_heading.style.color = 'blue';
```

Commonly used with an id selector `#single-header-id`.

[Here's a demo](http://jsbin.com/nekewa/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 1):

If you mean to select a `h1` that is *before* the *first* element of class `desleft`, you could always do this:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("desleft")[0].previousSibling.previousSibling
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Xeon06/ZMJJk/

`previousSibling` needs to be called twice because of the empty text node between the two. That's why using libraries to do this stuff is really the best way to go.

Comment: Note that this won't work on older versions of IE. (need IE9 at least I think)  No jQuery is a real pisser when you're doing stuff like this, I've gotten so use to not worrying about DOM quirks.

Comment: I've never used previousSibling before, will go through that, Thanks :)

Comment: @jondavidjohn : Thanks, did not know that. Back to more coding to find elements :/

Comment: @Aaditi, if you need to support older browsers and can't use a third-party library, I'd get ready to write a LOT more code.

Comment: Believe it is being pushed as html5 (FF3, Chrome and Opera 9+) already support it.

Comment: @jondavidjohn : Guess, will just give id's to everything.That seems to be the way out.No sense in writing extra code for transversals, that too for extinct browsers :/

Answer (score 0):

```
var h1 = document.querySelector('.desleft').previousElementSibling;
```

1. Find element with className='desleft' using selector '.desleft'
2. Just move back to previous element (not to previous node!)