# Replace dynamic html code/content without getelementbyid and innerhtml? (it stops the rest of the site loading and breaks other scripts)

Tags: javascript, html, replace, innerhtml

i have a website that i can't control all of the content of. I want to replace some code but the only methods that work seem to wreck everything else. (page won't load past the script, all other javascripts don't work etc)

The site is a print store, and the so the products have their own id, but i want to change them all

Here's an example of the code in which I want to replace some attributes on images. the code generated by the server which I can't control. (EDITED FOR CLARITY OF MY QUESTION, FULL CODE AROUND THE IMAGES ADDED. Indents edited to focus on div, table, and img)

```
 <div id="divProduct">

       <div style="float:left;"><center>
 <table class="f2"><tr><td><a href='/diy/mousepad/small-mousepad-93' >
 <img  width='120' height='120' id='P276' src='http://c1.vip-stores.com/img/1-276-0-2-1'  alt='Small Mousepad' title='Small Mousepad' border='0' /><br>
         </a></td></tr></table>
         <a href='/diy/mousepad/small-mousepad-93' >Custom Small Mousepad</a>
         <br /><div class='fs_textsmallprice'>Price:$7.45</div><br />
         </center>
       </div>

       <div style="float:left;"><center>
 <table class="f2"><tr><td><a href='/diy/mousepad/large-mousepad-160' >
 <img  width='120' height='120' id='P465' src='http://c1.vip-stores.com/img/1-465-0-2-1'  alt='Large Mousepad' title='Large Mousepad' border='0' /><br>
         </a></td></tr></table><a href='/diy/mousepad/large-mousepad-160' >                 Custom Large Mousepad </a><br />
         <div class='fs_textsmallprice'>Price:$7.45</div>
         <br /></center>
       </div> 
ETC....
```

I want to replace the width and height on all images from 120 to 150, and the last 3 digits in the src link on all images from 0-2-1 to 0-1-1 which loads a higher resolution version.

GetElementById works if i enter the id of course, but i want to effect all products that load on the page. There are over 1000 products in the store and they display depending on categories and searches etc. You get the idea.

The following seems to break everything and i heard it was dangerous to use, but it also works:

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/0-2-1/g, '0-1-1');
```

How can I do this safely with JAVASCRIPT, using some kind of wildcard with the src and id or whatever?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7353641/javascript-selectors

Comment: This sounds like something a "query selector" would be great for. But, to get it in the most specific way, it might be helpful to know what the immediate-surrounding HTML of these images is, as I doubt these are the only images on the page. For instance: If all these images show up under a "productListing" class, you could select all of them with the query ".productListing img".

Comment: @SableFoste I start to get the feeling that commenters are now being a bit too liberal with the "Possible duplicate" suggestions. Yes, that answer solves his problem. It's still not fair to call it a "duplicate" though. It's like saying "How can I get all these boxes into town?" is a duplicate of "Where can I obtain, and learn how to use, a truck?"

Comment: Yes there can be many images, arranged in a grid. The image grid list is preceded by  <div id="divProduct"> if that helps.

Comment: Thanks everyone, but I feel that other post doesn't solve my problem, or i'm too much of a noob to realise it. Would anyone be kind enough to give an example code for my situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not directly do what you want instead of dealing with the string representation of the HTML using regex?

```
var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');


for (var i=0; i<images.length; i++) {
    var img = images[i];

    if (img.width == '120' && img.height == '120') {
        img.width = '150';
        img.height = '150';
    }

    img.src = img.src.replace(/0-2-1$/, '0-1-1');
}
```

Comment: LEGEND! thank you!! 

I'll post another question about changing some other things - like if altering the code is possible (like removing a <td ></td> and changing table background colors).

I thought the answer might be in a single line of code, and assume the above solution is the not the way to go for changing any piece of html code

Comment: Part of the key to it is this: Remember that your browser isn't working with sets of <etc> tags internally; it translates those into a Document Object Model (DOM), then throws out the "HTML" that tells it how to build that DOM. Javascript can work very well directly on those DOM objects (take some time looking through some of the methods and selectors available if you like), although one way to effectively create a number of them is by inputting HTML using "innerHTML" - that method should not often be used though.

Comment: @GeneralNoob Also: If slebetman helped you, please be sure to mark his answer as the solution!

Comment: If you feel kind, upvote AND accept :D - I'll get more points!!

Comment: I tried clicking the up arrow but it said i needed a 15 reputation or something. but i'll click the tick now :)

Answer (score 0):

if inside your divProduct are no other images you can use this:

```
mainWrapper = document.getElementById('divProduct');
setOfImages = mainWrapper.getElementByTagName('img');

for (var x=0; x< setOfImages.length; x++){
// your img is in setOfImages[i];
// your magic of changing stuff
}
```