# How to select specific elements inside of another specific divs with query selector?

Tags: javascript, css

code is like this

```
<div class="linkPillar">
  <a href="github"><img src="github.png" alt="GitHub"></a>
  <a href="facebook"><img src="fb.png" alt="facebook"></a>
</div>
```

and i want to select all a's just inside of linkPillar without giving each of them an id. is there any way to make this, thanks

Comment: You mean `document.querySelectorAll('.linkPillar a');`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [javascript selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7353641/javascript-selectors)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the query selector to find the elements:

```js
console.log(document.querySelectorAll('.linkPillar a'));
```

```html
<div class="linkPillar">
        <a href="github"><img src="github.png" alt="GitHub"></a>
        <a href="facebook"><img src="fb.png" alt="facebook"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: This is awesome. We can mix CLASS and ID selectors and up to unlimited levels.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `getElementsByClassName()` method to return a collection of all elements in the document with the class name "linkPillar" and then use `querySelectorAll` to fetch all of the a tag elements within that element.

```js
var linkPillar = document.getElementsByClassName("linkPillar")[0]; 
var aTags = linkPillar.querySelectorAll("a"); 
console.log(aTags);
```

```html
<div class="linkPillar">
   <a href="github"><img src="github.png" alt="GitHub"></a>
   <a href="facebook"><img src="fb.png" alt="facebook"></a>
</div>
<a href="twitter"><img src="twitter.png" alt="Twitter"></a>
```